# Which is original MacBook Pro 15" Charger

Tags: macbook-pro, charger

i have MacbookPro with retina display, model **A1398**

```
MacBook Pro "Core i7" 2.3 15" Retina 2012   2.3 GHz Core i7 (I7-3615QM)
```

I have to buy a new charger and I'm not sure which to buy (EU - Bosnia)? :/

On the Internet I found that the original chargers manufactured by a Delta Electronics.

[image: Delta electronics charger]

A friend has Air -**Mid2012**. It looks like the image 2 (LITEON TECHNOLOGY). He bought a Macbook Air 2013. at the Apple authorised reseller..

[image: LITEON Technology corporation]

Comment: How is your friend's laptop charging spec related to your question? Also, where do you plan to buy your charger - used or new, online, in an Apple shop, what?

Comment: New one at reseller apple shop

Answer (score 1):

The above picture should be the correct one to buy. Do ensure that when purchasing on the internet, you purchase the correct one for your country's port (EU in this case) and that it is genuine. (Delta Electronics is the manufacturer for the charger, yes)

[Source](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201700) (see under `Computers that use the 85W MagSafe 2 Adapter`)

Comment: Which "above picture" are you referring to?